# How to manage underlying interface changes in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Somewhere between emacs 23.1 and 24.1, the interface of `url-retrieve` changed.  In emacs 23.1, it looks like this:

```
(url-retrieve URL CALLBACK &optional CBARGS)
```

In version 24.1, it looks like this:

```
(url-retrieve URL CALLBACK &optional CBARGS SILENT INHIBIT-COOKIES)
```

I have an emacs package that uses this function.  I'd like to take advantage of the new *SILENT* argument on emacs 24.1, while maintaining backwards compatibility with older versions of emacs that don't support it.

What's the best way to manage this?  Can I grab the maximum number of arguments at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun try-call-with-more-args (function a b c d)
  (condition-case var
      (progn
        (funcall function a b c d)
        (message "there was no error"))
    (wrong-number-of-arguments (funcall function a b c))))

(try-call-with-more-args #'message "b = %d, c = %d" 1 2 3)
```

Even though the one posted by Trey Jackson is much smarter, this is simpler and, actually has a good chance of working, even if you are targeting a native C function :)

Comment: It would be fun to write a recursive version of this; keep dropping one from the arglist until (hopefully) successful.

Comment: You have a missing `(progn ...)` wrapping the `funcall' and `message'.
Furthermore, you should not catch `error` but only `wrong-number-of-arguments` so as to reduce the risk of falling back on the old calling convention because of some unrelated error.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to get the argument list:

```
(defun my-get-arglist (obj)
  ;; code taken from disassemble-internal
  (let ((macro 'nil)
        (name 'nil)
        (doc 'nil)
        args)
    (while (symbolp obj)
      (setq name obj
            obj (symbol-function obj)))
    (if (subrp obj)
        (error "Can't disassemble #<subr %s>" name))
    (if (and (listp obj) (eq (car obj) 'autoload))
        (progn
          (load (nth 1 obj))
          (setq obj (symbol-function name))))
    (if (eq (car-safe obj) 'macro)  ;handle macros
        (setq macro t
              obj (cdr obj)))
    (if (and (listp obj) (eq (car obj) 'byte-code))
        (setq obj (list 'lambda nil obj)))
    (if (and (listp obj) (not (eq (car obj) 'lambda)))
        (error "not a function"))
    (if (consp obj)
        (if (assq 'byte-code obj)
            nil
          (setq obj (byte-compile obj))))
    (cond ((consp obj)
           (setq obj (cdr obj))     ;throw lambda away
           (setq args (car obj))    ;save arg list
           (setq obj (cdr obj)))
          ((byte-code-function-p obj)
           (setq args (aref obj 0)))
          (t (error "Compilation failed")))
    args))
```

Comment: I have to go with "check the version number" as a solution, but this is a neat tool to have.

Answer (score 3):

You could check `emacs-major-version` and make sure it's >= 24.

Comment: I still think this is generally the sanest solution to the problem (and it's the simplest as well). For other use cases, the `emacs-minor-version` or just `emacs-version` variables may also apply. The various `version*` function can be used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the older emacs version, write a wrapper around the older function:

```
(let ((orig-fun #'symbol-name-of-orig-fun))
  (defun symbol-name-of-orig-fun (arglist of new function interface)
    (declare (ignore new function interface))
    (funcall orig-fun arglist of)))
```

This generates a lexical closure that stores the reference of the old function within the new function. I don't know the emacs dialect, but I would bet this pattern could be used in emacs. I use it every once in a while in common lisp.

Comment: Lexical binding in Emacs versions < 24 is not that simple (and in 24 requires an explicit declaration in the file that lexical binding can be used).

Comment: Go with a dynamic global then: Change the let to a defvar, put earmuffs around the var name, and place it at the top level